# How to calculate the process correctly using Feynman diagrams?

Tags: quantum-field-theory, feynman-diagrams, perturbation-theory, interactions

The general approach of perturbation theory is familiar to me, only a slight clarification. We describe the interaction of two particles. For this, one must first take into account the contribution of the zero-order approximation diagram (without interaction), and then the contribution with one or two interaction elements (first approximation), and so on. Do I understand correctly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The question is a bit vague, thus the answer will also be quite vague.

First of all when you say that you want to "calculate the process" you have to be more specific. What do you want do to? For example:

- You may want to calculate the probability that the system will go from state $1$ to state $2$(in the case you mentioned, these states are two-particle states). In this case, what you want to do is calculate the $S$-matrix.
- On the other hand you may want to calculate the Green function for your system. From here you can determine renormalization, life-time...

Any one of these cases can be calculated using Feynman diagrams. They basically represent the pictorial method to do perturbation theory.

> For this, one must first take into account the contribution of the zero-order approximation diagram (without interaction)

Yes. The zeroth-order approximation represents the case if the particles wouldn't be interacting at all. Thus, in perturbation theory this represents the simplest (zeroth-order) approximation. The corresponding Feynman diagrams do not have any vertices. The number of vertices represent the order of perturbation theory. Thus first order approximation Feynman diagrams would only have one vertex. This is the lowest non-trivial (interacting) approximation. If you want to go even further, then you would need Feynman diagrams with two vertices. In theory if you accounted infinitely many diagrams you would get the perfectly correct result. Although in turns out that even if you could sum all the diagrams it is not so straightforward to obtain the exact result because the series you get with Feynman diagrams is in fact [Asymptotic expansion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Asymptotic_expansion). This means that in the case when you have many diagrams, you should not just sum them, but you need to to do something called [Pade transformation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pad%C3%A9_approximant) which is probably advanced for you in this point in time. For example in QED this becomes important if you have more than 137 diagrams (which you will never have)...

Comment: Thanks for the answer. That is, the zero-order diagram also contributes to the total amplitude. Now it is clear. I'm still a student and I'm still learning the basics.

Comment: One question.The contribution of the diagram is inversely proportional to the number of vertices (if the coupling constant is small). How to calculate the contribution of a diagram without vertices?

Comment: Again, it depends on whether you are calculating the S matrix, the Green function or something else. In general, zeroth order is not something that needs any calculation. It is known from free theory. For example, in the case of S matrix it is just the delta function. In the case of Green function it is just the noninteracting (free) Green function.

Comment: The contribution of diagram is typically proportional to the coupling constant raised to the power $n$, where $n$ is the number of vertices. Thus, the zeroth diagram is "proportional to 1", first order is proportional to $\alpha$, second order to $\alpha^2$... where $\alpha$ is the coupling constant.

Comment: I mean, the zero-order diagram also contributes to the total amplitude and is also needed, and it also affects the result. Thanks for answers!