# Is the contribution of diagrams without vertices taken into account in calculating the process amplitude?

Tags: quantum-field-theory, particle-physics, feynman-diagrams, perturbation-theory, interactions

It seems I have finally decided on the question. When expanding the interaction process in a perturbation theory series, it is also necessary to take into account the contribution of the diagrams in which no interaction occurs? As in the first two diagrams in the figure.
[image]

Comment: I think it depends on what you're trying to compute. Usually we calculate the S-matrix _without_ the trivial part corresponding to no scattering, but of course for the "full" S-matrix they should be included (this point is sometimes glossed over)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Consider the Dyson series for the S-matrix:
$$
S = \lim_{t\to\infty} U(-t, +t) = \mathcal{T}\exp\left(-i\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\mathrm{d}^4 x \ \mathcal{H}(x)\right)
$$
Expanding out the first few terms, we see that this is
$$
S = \mathcal{T}\left[\color{red}1-i\int \mathrm{d}^4x \ \mathcal{H}(x) + \frac{-i^2}{2!}\iint \mathrm{d}^4x \ \mathrm{d}^4y \ \mathcal{H}(x)\mathcal{H}(y)+\dots \right]
$$

Usually, when people talk about computing the S-matrix, they are really talking about the *transfer matrix* $T$, in which the trivial $1$ part is discarded, corresponding to ignoring the processes in which there is no interaction (zero vertex diagrams). In fact, most people take it a step further and really talk about evaluating the "amplitude" $\mathcal{M}_{fi}$, which is defined as
$$
S_{fi} = \langle f|S|i\rangle = \delta_{fi}-iT_{fi} = \delta_{fi}-i(2\pi)^4\delta^4(p_f-p_i)\mathcal{M}_{fi}
$$

For the "full" S-matrix defined by the Dyson formula though, the trivial diagrams must be included.

Answer (score 0):

The answer is no, there is no meaning to the first two , because in the crossection for the interaction ,the term "interaction" means there is energy-momentum exchange. The Feynman diagrams are a pictorial representation of how that exchange happens, breaking that down to the perturbative terms. [This link](https://www.hep.phy.cam.ac.uk/%7Echpotter/particleandnuclearphysics/Lecture_05_FeynmanDiagrams.pdf) may help you

> Each Feynman diagram represents a term in the perturbation theory expansion of the matrix element for an interaction.Normally, a full matrix element contains an infinite number of Feynman diagrams.

[image: feynmadiag]

There is no term with no vertex.

Comment: You have to start with free field theory. Only then can you turn on the interaction and read the corrections. And, of course, a diagram without interaction has its own amplitude, since ALL stories must be considered. It’s obvious to me that you’re not good at theory.

Comment: I gave you a link for my statements, where is yours? Free field theory describes nothing, it is mathematics, if it exists at all. Physics is about measurements and obervations.

Comment: https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/606461/how-to-calculate-the-process-correctly-using-feynman-diagrams

Comment: this answer is about non interacting, if there is no interaction there is no measurement to check  , I can find no zero order here http://web.mit.edu/tabbott/www/papers/feynman-diagrams.pdf feynman diagram,. Here it talks of "unlinked diagrams" https://eduardo.physics.illinois.edu/phys582/582-chapter11-edited.pdf,which  might enlighten you , if you can wade through it.

Comment: @anna v To calculate the total scattering matrix, it is also necessary to take into account the contribution of the non-interacting component.

Comment: @ArmanArmenpress  why is it not seen in the total amplitude I quote above?

Comment: Read the answer from Nihar Karve.